# finding the digit sum in a arthematic sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, range

I have a very simple question. I will be provided with the first term of Arithmetic Progression and the common difference. I am required to give sum of digits of all numbers in between the range of L and R.Here the sum means the sum <10 that means for a number say 157, the sum of digits is 1+5+7=13 which is further 1+3=4. The range is the index of the elements. L means the Lth number of that series and L starts from 1.Here L and R can be of range 1 to 10^18. How can i find the sum of these digits for such a large range. I know the digit sum of a number n can be calculated as (n-1)%9+1. But i can't iterate over 10^18 numbers.

Example: let say First term of Arithmetic Progression is 14 and common difference 7.Then the sum of digits of all numbers between 2 and 4 will be sum of (2+1)=3 and (2+8)=(1+0)=1 and (3+5)=8 which is equal to 12

for pattern finding

```
 current=first;
  ll arr[10]={0};
  while(1)// search for the pattern
  {
      ll dsum=(current-1)%9+1;// calculating digit sum
      if(arr[dsum]!=0)
        break;
      arr[dsum]=ptr;// saving the value in the array by using hashing
      ptr++;
      current+=c_diff;
  }
for sum

    for(ll i=1;i<ptr;i++)
  {
      sum[i]=sum[i-1]+new_arr[i];
  }
```

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You have to try something first and you can show others what you have done and what is the specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Hint: does that sequence (S(14, 7, 2) = {3, 1, 8, ...}) ever repeat? Prove it. You'll be well on the way to a big simplification of the problem.

Comment: @Beta I have made certain observations. The pattern is repeating after certain interval. Like for the series 3,6,9,12,15,18,21... the digit sum is as 3,6,9,3,6,9. I have applied the same strategy but i got WA for some of the test cases. So i am not able to understand where my test cases are getting failed. That is why i asked the question.

Comment: `for sum` looks as funny as the name of `ptr` (aside from being an abbrev., is it used for counting or pointing?). You comment `saving the value in the array [using] hashing`. To sum, you do not use a single "accumulator", but fill a `sum` array with partial sums over _consecutive_ array elements, leaving off at `prt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of your numbers will be (ultimately) reduced to a single digit, you *must* be having repetition after certain number of terms, and, that is maximum of 9. (because 10 digits, but 0 not possible to repeat).

So, lets start with an example. Say, `a=14, d=7, l=2, r=50`. I've changed the value of `r` from your example.

So, trying to find repetition:

- Our repetition array is `q` (say). Then, 1st term of `q` is `5` (since 14 = 5).
- Now, next term is 21 (= 3). Since 3 is not equal to 5, we continue.
- We find all terms till we get 5 again. So, `q` will be like this in this example:

  ```
  q[] = {5,3,1,8,6,4,2,9,7}   ...  and then we have 5 again, so stop.
  ```

So, our repetitive pattern has 9 members. Now, find a cumulative sum array with this, which will be like:

```
sum[] = {5,8,9,17,23,27,29,38,45}
```

Now, since `r=50`, find sum of `r` terms, which will be:

```
(floor)(50/9) * 45 + sum[50%9]
= 5 * 45 + 23
= 248
```

Now, similarly, find sum of `l-1` terms, (since you have to find sum in range `l..r` inclusive.

Sum of 1st (2-1) = 1 terms will be:

```
(floor)(1/9) * 45 + sum[1 % 9]
= 0 + 5
= 5
```

So, the answer is, 248 - 5 = 243.

Comment: maximum of 9 terms can be repetitive not 10

Comment: Sure, `0` will be there.

Comment: I have implemented the same approach but i am getting WA for some cases where L and R can be of range 10^18.

Comment: how 0  can be there? our first term of ap can't be zero (it is in the question)

Comment: Oh, ok. Then its 9 terms, I've made the edit for that.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you getting WA. You must be leaving some corner case. If this problem is from some online judge, can you give me the link.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is `ptr` or `new_arr`. You only need the cumulative sum array starting from 1st term (which is `sum[]` in my example), its size (which in my case is 9) and total sum (which here is 45)

Answer (score 0):

well you can solve this problem by taking two arrays of elements 9 and finding the  lth term element.
 from the lth term find the  digit sum of lth element and save it in two  array respectively .

> w1=a+(l-1)*d
>   for(i=1,j=w1;i<=9;j+=d,i++){   
>  if(j%9==0){
> array1[i]=9 ;
> array2[i]=9;
> }
> else{
> array1[i]=j%9;
> array2[i]=j%9;}
>                                    }
>   now   q = r-l+1 
>   w= q/9 and e=q%9
>   array1[i]=array1[i]*w // in loop from i= 1 to 9
>   in array2[i]=0 //new loop from i=e+1 to 9
>   now digitsum += array1[i]+array2[i] // from a a loop i=1 to 9 and  digitsum is the sum of all digit of sequence
>
> this digit sum is solution.